# How to access children property on snapshot in flutter?

Tags: swift, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I used to write snapshot.children.allObjects in swift. How do I write this code in Flutter with firebase?
If I use a snapshot.value as! [String: Any] snapshot's nodes are not retrieved in order from the database. Is there any other option to retrieve objects in order from the Firebase console?

```
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
            else { return completion(nil, []) }
        
        snapshot.forEach({ (postSnapshot) in
            print(postSnapshot)
        })
    })
```

Comment: is this real-time database or firestore?

Comment: It's real-time database.